# yield return in recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, yield

i am attempting to create an

```
    IEnumrable<PropertyInfo>
```

iv'e got a method called Disassemble which iterates recursively throw a given object and all it's child objects of it's properties .

**please do not concern your self with the Inner wrapper objects of type INameValueWrapper**

The problem below is when i encounter a property which is a Class i wan't to call Disassemble on it as well 
and add it to the same iteration of the IEnumrable , the Dissasemble does not occur again when it is called 
where i put the comment :
    **// The problem is here .**

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Dissasemble<T>(this object sourceObj) where T : INameValueWrapper
    {
        var properties = sourceObj.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            var wrapper = (T)prop.WrapPropertyInfo(sourceObj);
            yield return wrapper;

            if (wrapper is CollectionPropertyInfoWrapper)
            {
                var colWrapper = wrapper as CollectionPropertyInfoWrapper;
                var collection = (IList)colWrapper.Value;

                int index = 0;
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    yield return (T)item.WrapItem(collection, index + 1);
                    index++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var propWrapper = wrapper as PropertyInfoWrapper;
                if (!propWrapper.IsPrimitive)
                {
                    var childObject = prop.GetValue(sourceObj);
                    childObject.Dissasemble<T>(); // here is the problem 
                }
            }
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

1) Why does it not get called and added to the iteration ?

2) What is the work around this issue ? ,

```
 i could call childObject.Dissasemble<T>().ToList() 
 and then iterate that collection calling yield return on it's items 
 but that seems like re doing something i already did.
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the method, but then ignoring the results. You may want something like:

```
foreach (var item in childObject.Disassemble<T>())
{
    yield return item;
}
```

I think you're a bit confused about what `yield return` does - it only yields a value *in the sequence returned by the currently-executing method*. It doesn't add a value to some global sequence. If you ignore the value returned by the recursive `Disassemble` call, the code won't even *execute* as iterator blocks are lazy. (They only execute code when they're asked for another value.)

Also, you don't need the `yield break;` at the end of your method.

Note that this if the recursion goes deep, this use of iterator blocks can be inefficient. That may well not be a problem for you, but it's something to think about. See posts by [Wes Dyer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx) and [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/18/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree.aspx) about this.

Comment: o'k got it , i thought the Jit compiler does know how to build a global sequence since it is in the scope of the original method.

Comment: @eranotzap: No, it's nothing to do with the JIT compiler. It's about how the C# language rules say it should behave. (You may well want to call the method but *not* yield the results, for example.)

Comment: doesn't the JitCompiler wrap the method in an IEnumrable object ?

Comment: @eranotzap: No, the C# compiler does. Or rather, it converts the method into a sort of state machine. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
childObject.Dissasemble<T>(); // here is the problem
```

try

```
foreach (var a in childObject.Dissasemble<T>())
{
 yield return a;
}
```