# IEnumerable yield and recursion - doesn't work

Tags: c#, recursion, ienumerable, yield

I'm trying to do something that combines using yield and recursion and I don't really understand why it's not working.

**Since my code is complicated, I've generated a simple example with the Fibonacci series:**

```
        private IEnumerable<int> fib()
        {
            int a1 = 1, a2 = 1;
            return fibRec(a1, a2);
        }

        private IEnumerable<int> fibRec(int a, int b)
        {
            int tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp + b;
            yield return a;
            fibRec(a, b);
        }
```

*Now, I know there are a 1000 ways of solving Fibonacci, but it's not the deal here. 
 this is only an example*.

Here is my call:

```
var nums = fib().Take(50).ToList();
```

The recursive call doesn't "work".
 I get the first yield to work OK and I don't really under stand why this suddenly stops when I try to call myself again.
Doing this with "while(true)" and no recursive call will work just fine.

Comment: Here's a working solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406446/refactoring-fibonacci-algorithm

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about what yield return does - it only yields a value in the sequence returned `by the currently-executing method.` [Jon Skeet's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953817/yield-return-in-recursion) SO question.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - I thought my problem was due to scope issues and I didn't know that yield works only in the current exe. method. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate though the enumerable returned by the recursive call and `yield return` each of the items explicitly.

```
    private IEnumerable<int> fibRec(int a, int b)
    {
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp + b;
        yield return a;
        foreach(int val in fibRec(a, b))
        {
             yield return val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's something that I didn't want to do. Is there any way to do what I wanted earlier or something similar?

Comment: @Amiros There is no other way.